# ubuntu get php files with lines longer than 160 characters

Tags: php, ubuntu

Are there a command that can I use for getting php files that contain one or more lines longer than nnn characters ?  (for example 160)

Developers coding checking.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't write bash script in ages, this was fun :D

```
#!/bin/bash

# search for php files in /var/www
files=($(find /var/www -type f -name "*.php"))

# loop file one by one
for file in "${files[@]}"
do

        # read file line by line
        while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

                # check is line longer than 160 chars
                if [ ${#line} -ge 160 ]; then

                        # output path to file and break
                        echo "$file" 
                        break
                fi
        done < "$file"
done
```

Comment: Advantages over the obviou `grep -RE '.{160}' .`?